# ASP.NET MVC Workshop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am an MVC developer since ASP.NET MVC Preview 1 and my company chose me as an instructor for an MVC 2 workshop. The session will last for 3 hours and I have not yet decided about the contents of the workshop.

What would you tell about MVC 2 in 3 hours to grab and keep the people's attention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Steven Sanderson's book, especially the bit about glib demos that don't tell the real story.

Some people suggest Nerddinner, but why not just point them at Hansellmann's video on the subject?  To be honest, you need Nerddinner to get an impression of how MVC works, and Steven Sanderson's book to get an impression of how to use MVC.

Still, I really don't think that this is a valid question, and don't know why the Stackoverflow police have not jumped on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You should watch some of the presentations on Channel 9.  And pick some topics that they go over...

1. [Basics](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman)
2. [NerdDinner](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T49F)

Answer (score 2):

It will depend of the kind of people will watch your workshop, it they are familiar with ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC or the MVC pattern, etc.

I think that the first and bigger concept behind the MVC is the separation of concerns, and you should show it and how it can help the developers, specially with the TESTING issue.

If people are not familiar with MVC, only this part would take a good time. If they're familiar and you want to talk specifically about the version 2 of the framework, I think the bigger changes from the previous one were:

- Areas
- Template Helpers
- DataAnnotation Attributes
- Model validator

With few examples, once 3 hours is few time to get deeper in each of these points. Would be nice to develop a few app live so they can see how easy it is.

Answer (score 2):

after introduction of mvc framework u can go on to include following topics

Routing (route constraints matching and custom route handlers)
   Model validation and custom
   validation attributes Security and authorization attributes Model
   binding default model binders and writing custom model binders
   custom html helpers
   Take a look at [13 extensibility points of mvc](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/08/13-asp.net-mvc-extensibility-points-you-have-to-know.aspx)

Comment: For some reason everybody always puts routing first. Why? It's like icing on the cake, SEO, or CSS. You don't need it to get started (or even at all!). I've seen many examples (and even some internal projects at my company) where devs go overboard on routes, then end up not using them or even defining ones that would match the default route anyway. My two cents.

Comment: for some rest like routing when ur controller has only methods like create, edit, delete etc. default routes are enough. there are times when ur project grows too big with hundreds of models and u can't or don't want to create a controller per entity. here u come to routing. Moreover, developers should know strengths of routing system, specially how they can restrict routing criteria by route constraints to accept id only as numeric field for instance

Answer (score 1):

Check out some of the presentations here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Scott Hanselman has a 73 minute one on the home page, that might be a good one to start with and mimic, as well as some of the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take them through building NerdDinner? http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html

Some of the Scott Hanselman videos out there on MVC are good, too, and might give you a small break from talking.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would cover is the flexibility of MVC. E.g., you have your choice of models and view languages. I would definitely cover the [Spark View Engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/), to give people an idea of how they can get away from code-centric (as opposed to markup-centric) view languages.

Comment: I don't think talking about alternative view engines is something to do at an internal training session. Rather I think a lead/informed dev should try some out, pick one and teach the session using that one.

Comment: @Ryan - you are right, I didn't catch the "training" part. Only the approaches being standardized on should be demoed in the session. Having said that, Spark is a good option!